# Image Resize with best resolution

Tags: image, resize, photoshop, image-resizing

Hi I have a image of 1000x662px in jpeg format and I want to resize image to 1536x200px with best resolution. I tried with photoshop CS4 but the resolution is very bad and its getting shrink. Please help me to resize image with best resolution. Thanks

Comment: You're changing the shape of the image... it's highly likely that it will look bad afterwards. Perhaps you could share the image?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because not about programming. It probably belongs on https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the very late response to your problem. What usually works for me is changing the image size by clicking "image>image size" or hitting CTRL+ALT+I

Input the resolution you want the picture at, in this case 1536xvariable and, making sure "resample image" is ticked at the bottom, select "Bicubic Smoother" and hit "Enter" and there we go!